# Lakshmana Rekha Mythology?

Tags: ramayana, history, lakshmana

Can you focus light on the Lakshmana Rekha power possessed by Lakshmana in the Ramayana?

Is there a Mythological story behind Lakshmana possessing this power ?

Had somebody crossed the Lakshmana Rekha, What would had been the consequences which included the mighty Ravana?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no mythological story behind Lakshmana possessing any special power. **He just prayed to the devatas after drawing the line** and establishing Sitaji in their care. He said that the **consequences of crossing the line would be that the said person’s head would get destroyed and make powder** i.e. burn and become ash.

The story as described in the Telugu Ranganatha Ramayana:

[image]

> After this, Lakshamana drew seven lines around the thatched hut and said, ”Oh mother, do not cross these lines and come outside. **If anyone tries to cross these lines his head will become powder that very instant.” Then he prayed to Agni establishing Sitaji in his care**, bowed down respectfully to Sitaji and left to find Ramaji.
> -*Ranganatha Ramayana Aranyakanda Chapter 18*

The story is the same even in the Bengali Krittibas Ramayana with a minor variation on the number of lines, not specifically mentioning Agni and not mentioning the consequences:

[image]

> Going out, Lakshmana drew a line all around and said no one shall enter the hut. He said, “**Oh devatas, Raghunatha his Vishnu himself and his wife is Sita. Please keep her.**”
> -*Sri Rama Panchali Aranya Kanda 32*

Comment: Where did you get the Krittibasi Ramayana printed in Hindi script ?

Comment: @AnubrataBit it’s available online. Actually they have the chaupai in northern style above this Bengali part so I read that.